# Me dice que falta sklearn pero que ya esta up-to-date en /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Tags: python-2.7, servidor

Sobre el servidor de mi empresa, cuando intento iniciar un fichero python me dice que me falta `sklearn` pero parece que ya existe.

```
:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python Main.py 
2017-07-24 14:01:55.852751
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import kmeans
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eclipse-Stats/kmeans.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn
:~/Eclipse-Stats$ pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Tal vez piense el terminal que no lo hay en el servidor pero, con la segunda commando, que lo tengo en el terminal ?

Parece que esta un problema de version porque cuando utiliso `python3 Main.py`, me dice el terminal que :

```
~/Eclipse-Stats$ python3 Main.py
  File "Main.py", line 113
    print "list of groups you can recommend : "
                                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Parece que funciona pero que sklearn no puede trabajar con python2.7

Como puedo cambiar la version de sklearn ?

Comment: Hola Marine, primero de todo, lo que comentas sobre Python 3 no prueba nada porque la sintaxis es evaluada antes, no importa que el import sea o no correcto, si hay un error de sintaxis ni llega a evaluar el import. ¿Tienes privilegios para usar `sudo`?

Comment: @FJSevilla, Gracias por la aclaración. Si pero me da `Requirement already up-to-date` tambien ...

Comment: Marine lo decía para que instalaras las dependencias primero `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools \
                     python-numpy python-scipy \
                     libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base` (esto puede causar lo que comentas) y para que probaras a usar el paquete de apt en vez de pip (`sudo apt-get install python-sklearn` ). De todas formas, sigue las instrucciones de la documentación, no deberias tener problemas: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#linux.

Comment: @FJSevilla Creo que señalas la verdadera razón: yo no tenía estas bibliotecas. Sin embargo, tras instalarlas, intento instalar `sklearn`. Entonces, intento hacer `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools \ python-numpy python-scipy \libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base` pero me decia que fue `Unable to locate package libatlas3gf-base`. Entonces seguí con `sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 \ /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3` pero hay `alternative /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3 for liblapack.so.3 not registered; not setting`

Comment: ¿Marine que versión de Ubuntu usas? Prueba a usar el paquete [libatlas3-base](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libatlas3-base) introducido a partir de trusty(14.04 LTS) en su lugar: `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy  libatlas-dev libatlas3-base`. De todas formas acabo de probar en Ubuntu 16.04 LTS en una máquina virtual y funciona a la perfección.

Comment: @FJSevilla 16.04. Tras tu comando intento hacer   sudo apt-get install python-sklearn pero me dice que `python-sklearn is already the newest version (0.17.0-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` Sin embargo cuando inicio el script sigue dicendome que falta sklearn : `ImportError: No module named sklearn`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62779/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-marine1).